# how to call variable from function to other function and reload the controller with the new string for the variable

Tags: codeigniter

I have controller called mycontroller , the index() loading the View , the view consist of form that action to other function call process() .
I want when the form submitting , the variable of process() updating and reload the controller again with the new value .

```js
<?php
class mycontroller extends CI_Controller{
$Myvar=null;
function index(){

$myarry=array('VariableToView'=>$this->$Myvar);
$this->load->view('myview',$myarry)
}
}
function process(){
$this->$myvar="Thanks";
}
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have `process()` reload (`redirect` to) "mycontroller/index" in order to show the message. But because the server does not "remember" any previous page request, the value of `$Myvar` will be lost during the redirect.

To pass data between server requests you will need to use sessions.

The `session` library requires that several preferences be set in the file  **application/config/config.php** - consult the documentation for the version of Codeigniter you are using to learn what must be done.

```
<?php

class Mycontroller extends CI_Controller
{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
  }

  function index()
  {
    //get session data. 
    $Myvar = $this->session->userdata('message');
    //If there is no session data named "message" then $Myvar will be "empty"
    if(empty($Myvar))
    {
      $Myvar = ""; //use an empty string
    }
    else
    {
      //the session has a "message" in userdata, 
      //remove that data so it won't be used the next time the page is loaded
      $this->session->unset_userdata('message');
    }
    $this->load->view('myview', array('VariableToView' => $Myvar));
  }

  function process()
  {
    //add userdata to session and redirect to mycontroller/index
    $data = array("message" => "Thanks");
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    redirect("mycontroller"); //will load mycontroller/index
  }

}
```